# How to auto populate data from other model and how to add calculated fields?

Tags: django, django-models

I am learning django and I have not been able to properly do two things within model clearance:

1. Within modelRetrieve the name fields that correspond to the imo number selected.
2. Autopopulate a date field with the current day plus 7 days.

Any ideas what I am doing wrong? Here is my code:

```
from django.db import models
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError
from django.utils import timezone
from datetime import timedelta, datetime

def imo_validator(value):
    if value < 0 or value > 9999999:
        raise ValidationError(
            'This is not a valid IMO number',
            params={'value':value},
            )  

class ship(models.Model):
    imo = models.IntegerField(unique=True,validators=[imo_validator])
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    rpm = models.FloatField()
    power = models.FloatField()
    main_engine = models.IntegerField()
    
    class Meta:
        ordering = ['imo']
        
    def __str__(self):
        return "{}, (IMO:{})".format(self.name, self.imo)

    
    
class clearance(models.Model):
    STATUSES = [
                ('PENDING','PENDING'),
                ('REJECTED','REJECTED'),
                ('APPROVED','APPROVED'),
               ]
    
    PORTS = [
            ('PACAN','PACAN'),
            ('PABLB','PABLB'),
            ('PACCT','PACCT'),
            ('PAANP','PAANP'),
            ('PAANA','PAANA'),
           ]

    date_of_request = models.DateField(default=timezone.now,blank=False,editable=True)
    imo = models.ForeignKey(ship, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    port = models.CharField(max_length=20,null=True,choices=PORTS)
    eta = models.DateField(null=False)

    name = ship.name.get(imo=imo)
    calculated_eta = models.DateField(datetime.today + timedelta(days=1))
          
    aduanas = models.FileField(blank=True)
    aduanas_ok = models.CharField(max_length=15,default='PENDING',choices=STATUSES,editable=False)
    minsa = models.FileField(blank=True)
    minsa_ok = models.CharField(max_length=15,default='PENDING',choices=STATUSES,editable=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return "{}, ETA:{}".format(self.imo, self.eta)
    
    class Meta:
        ordering = ['eta']
```

Answer (score 0):

To add a default to a DateField that is 7 days in the future you need to create a function that returns the date 7 days in the future and then pass that to the ["default"](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.Field.default) parameter of the field

```
def seven_days_from_now():
    return datetime.date.today() + datetime.timedelta(days=7)


class clearance(models.Model):
    ...
    calculated_eta = models.DateField(default=seven_days_from_now)
    ...
```

Your "name" field should be a [property](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#property) that returns the name of the associated "imo"

```
class clearance(models.Model):
    ...
    @property
    def name(self):
        return self.imo.name
    ...
```